# Clicking on "Show all results" in a W|A pod hangs Mathematica

Tags: front-end, wolfram-alpha-queries

I am trying the brand new trial version.

I type in `=Forest Gump`, then the Enter key.

The input turns into a box with a plus sign in the upper right corner. When I hover over the plus sign, it displays "Show all results".

When I click on the plus sign, some data is displayed (looks like W|A), then *Mathematica* is hung ("Not Responding" according to Task Manager).

I kill it.

Does anyone have any idea what is wrong? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Environment:

$\quad \quad$ Version 10.0.2.0
$\quad \quad$ OS: Windows 8.1

Should I wait for 10.1?

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem on my system -- V10.0.2 running under OS X 10.6.8. You might try `==Forest Gump` if you want a fuller answer from W|A.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
WolframAlpha["Forest Gump", "FullOutput"]
```

runs about 1 sec. on my computer. Hint: Make sure you have fast Internet connection.
Here an extract of screenshot of result [image]

Comment: This works. I am not sure if that is what the button shows, but it allows me to continue my testing..Thx

Comment: yes , the button shows the same result. works on my computer.